# spring mvs vs jax-rs rest

Tags: spring-mvc, jax-rs

Any reason why i should choose jax-rs (jersey ) instead of Spring-mvc for rest implementation.

Spring comes with additional features in addition to rest like aop , security , ioc etc. .
You get all you need form spring.

Any performance/features drawbacks choosing spring (i suspect that ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAX-RS pros:

1. JSR standard
2. Can be run without servlet container (grizzly, simple, ...)
3. Production-ready implementations (jersey, cxf, resteasy, restlet, ...)
4. designed for REST applications only

Spring MVC pros:

1. Provide "full" stack, not just REST facilities
2. Dependency injection / AOP / Transactions
3. Pluggable view templates (JSP, freemarker, velocity, ...)

I've never noticed performances bottlenecks with one or other, except spring application take a longer time to deploy and warm-up.